# How to upload Selenium python with django in the heroku, I'm getting h12 error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, selenium, heroku

I'm doing test python, selenium, django and heroku a quick query on google and return to the template I'm taking error timeout h12, all my applications are with the same error, I'm not sure how to configure this in my script, 
I can not set the worker in the background.

error:

```
2018-10-20T02:06:48.131091+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 
desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/" host=testeseleniu.herokuapp.com 
request_id=74b149
f3-48dc-4e1c-97f3-616d3564cc8c fwd="201.81.178.239" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 
service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

View.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os


class consuappView(View):


    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'consuapp/consulta.html')

    def post(self, request):


        chrome_exec_shim = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN", "chromedriver")
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.binary_location = chrome_exec_shim
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver', 
        chrome_options=chrome_options)
        self.campo_cep_site = request.POST['cep']
        self.campo_num_site = request.POST['num']
        self.driver.get("https://www.google.com.br")
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 280)
        self.google(wait, self.campo_cep_site)
        self.driver.close()

        return render(request, 'consuapp/consulta.html', {'retorno_consulta': 
        self.retorno_consulta})


    def google(self, wait, campo_cep_site):

        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'lst- 
        ib'))).send_keys(campo_cep_site)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'tsf'))).submit()

        form_emp = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('xpdopen')
        self.retorno_consulta = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//* 
        [@id="rhs_block"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/
        div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]').text
```

Buildpack:

1. heroku/python
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.git
3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome

In localhost it's working, time to consult is 5.3 seconds.
only heroku crashed.